# GSUTIL cp file from server to bucket and make file public

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Using this command in my server from a php file:

```
exec(gsutil cp /path/to/file/on/server/namefile.ext gs://nameBucket/dir/namefile.ext > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

i got the namefile.ext on bucket, in the correct directory...but need to make this file public readable.

Already tried to put this command (at the end of file, for make that public) but nothing to do:

```
exec(gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://nameBucket/dir/namefile.ext > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

So, **upload works** but I need to make file **readable without my interaction from "browser"** of bucket. There is a way to do this? Maybe into *cp* command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer` command you used is meant to make all objects in a bucket publicly readable, but you provided it with the url of the object.

So, if you want to make the specific file publicly readable:

```
gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://nameBucket/dir/namefile.ext
```

If you want to make all objects in a bucket publicly readable:

```
gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://nameBucket/
```

This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).

Comment: For the `acl ch` command above, the IAM alternative is `gsutil iam ch allUsers:legacyObjectReader gs://bucket/obj`.  You can check out what roles are available at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles.